# IndexOutOfBounds Exception when filling multidimensional array

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I have some xml data I am looping through. I would like to store each "entry" in an array spot in order to see it with an intent.putExtras(). My data has 3 elements: latlon,name,description. I would like to put each in my array. So I am setting it up like so: markerInfo[i][0] = Loc; etc... like so:

```
 final List<XmlDom> entries = xml.tags("Placemark");
            int i = entries.size();
int j=0;
            for (XmlDom entry : entries) {
                XmlDom lon = entry.tag("longitude");
                XmlDom lat = entry.tag("latitude");
                XmlDom name = entry.tag("name");
                XmlDom desc = entry.tag("description");

                String cdatareplace = desc.toString();
                String description = cdatareplace.replace("<![CDATA[", "");
                description = description.replace("]]>", "");

                final String firename = name.text();
                final String firedesc = description;

                String geoLon = lon.text();
                String geoLat = lat.text();

                String coor = lat + "," + lon;
                // Log.e("COORS: ", coor);

                double lati = Double.parseDouble(geoLat);
                double lngi = Double.parseDouble(geoLon);

                LOCATION = new LatLng(lati, lngi);

                String Loc = LOCATION.toString();

                String[][] markerInfo = new String[i][3];

                markerInfo[j][0] = Loc; 
                markerInfo[j][1] = firename;
                markerInfo[j][2] = firedesc;

                Log.e("MARKERINFO",markerInfo[j][0]);
                Log.e("MARKERINFO",markerInfo[j][1]);
                Log.e("MARKERINFO",markerInfo[j][2]);

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(LOCATION)
                        .title(markerInfo[j][1])
                        .snippet(markerInfo[j][2])
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.wfmi_icon48)));
                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                        // Show full description in new activity.

                        // fireDesc(arg0.getTitle(), arg0.getSnippet());

                        Intent i = new Intent(Map.this, MapSingleActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("name", arg0.getTitle())
                                .putExtra("description", arg0.getSnippet())
                                .putExtra("lat", arg0.getPosition().latitude)
                                .putExtra("lon", arg0.getPosition().longitude);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
j++;
            }
```

I am getting array index out of bounds. I figured if I filled it with the entries.size() that would not be the problem, so maybe i am not telling it how big correctly?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where is `j` defined?

Comment: @Pawel just above the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the second dimension is also big enough

Fix it by changing the declaration of `markerInfo` to:

```
String[][] markerInfo = new String[i][3];
```

At the moment you are only creating `i` empty `String` arrays. With the above code you will create `i` arrays that can hold three `String` objects each.

Also, at the moment you are writing to the last location which is outside of the array bounds.

You need to change it to write to an available location. If you are trying to write to the last available location that would be `i-1`.

```
markerInfo[i-1][0] = Loc; 
markerInfo[i-1][1] = firename;
markerInfo[i-1][2] = firedesc;
```

Looking at your code however, it seems like you may want to **declare `markerInfo` outside of the loop** and create a counter variable that you increment at each step of the loop.

Comment: ah, you caught my post before the edit. sorry. I added that in there, but still get the array out of bounds...

Comment: Thanks that helped. I am trying to pass some data and thought this might be the way... but looks like I am only still able to get what I was getting before fill the mdarray... blah...

Answer (score 2):

Second size of the array is 0 - `new String[i][0]`. Then you try to insert something on position 0,1,2, which are not available.

Even if you write `new String[i][3]`, then the maximum index is `i-1`.